# CRASH attempt to delete and reload the same index path

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios8, collectionview, photokit

> CollectionViewController.m line 439
>   __50-[CollectionViewController photoLibraryDidChange:]_block_invoke

Fatal Exception: NSInternalInconsistencyException
attempt to delete and reload the same index path ( {length = 2, path = 0 - 26007})

```
- (void)photoLibraryDidChange:(PHChange *)changeInstance
{
    // Call might come on any background queue. Re-dispatch to the main queue to handle it.
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

        // check if there are changes to the assets (insertions, deletions, updates)
        PHFetchResultChangeDetails *collectionChanges = [changeInstance changeDetailsForFetchResult:self.assetsFetchResults];
        if (collectionChanges) {

            // get the new fetch result
            self.assetsFetchResults = [collectionChanges fetchResultAfterChanges];

            UICollectionView *collectionView = self.collectionView;

            if (![collectionChanges hasIncrementalChanges] || [collectionChanges hasMoves]) {
                // we need to reload all if the incremental diffs are not available
                [collectionView reloadData];

            } else {
                // if we have incremental diffs, tell the collection view to animate insertions and deletions
                [collectionView performBatchUpdates:^{
                    NSIndexSet *removedIndexes = [collectionChanges removedIndexes];
                    if ([removedIndexes count]) {
                        [collectionView deleteItemsAtIndexPaths:[removedIndexes aapl_indexPathsFromIndexesWithSection:0]];
                    }
                    NSIndexSet *insertedIndexes = [collectionChanges insertedIndexes];
                    if ([insertedIndexes count]) {
                        [collectionView insertItemsAtIndexPaths:[insertedIndexes aapl_indexPathsFromIndexesWithSection:0]];
                    }
                    NSIndexSet *changedIndexes = [collectionChanges changedIndexes];
                    if ([changedIndexes count]) {
                        [collectionView reloadItemsAtIndexPaths:[changedIndexes aapl_indexPathsFromIndexesWithSection:0]];
                    }
                } completion:NULL];
            }

            [self resetCachedAssets];
        }
    });
}
```

source: https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/wwdc_2014/wwdc_2014_sample_code/exampleappusingphotosframework.zip

I can't replicate the issue. What could be the problem? Thanks a lot!

Comment: I have seen that before, haven't been able to reproduce it lately but what I'm seeing now all the time is an assertion failure *** Assertion failure in -[UICollectionView _endItemAnimations], /SourceCache/UIKit/UIKit-3318.93/UICollectionView.m:3720 and then *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'attempt to delete item 9 from section 0 which only contains 9 items before the update'. This is strange as I have the exact same code as the application from the sample, just that the app is more complex and that it's based in Swift. :(

Comment: Also, another one I've seen with this method is related to assertion errors in the number of final items not matching the previous count plus the sum. I believe there might be an issue with the way those indexes are calculated and passed to the listeners or maybe there has to be an additional validation on our end on the arrays to verify with the current state of the collection view after the fetch result updates are pulled. Honestly, this has been one of the most frustrating parts of the app I'm working on right now.

Comment: Is anyone created radar? I will do it. I tested the latest code which was updated to iOS 10 and Swift 3 and it is still constantly crashing.

Comment: I've tested similar code which crashed with the same error you had in iOS 10 with Xcode 8 beta 2 and it is not crashing any more. As I suspected, this was a bug in UIKit.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I was able to reproduce this today. To do this you need to:

1. Open your app that is listening for changes
2. Open the photos app, save a set of photos to your photo library from an iCloud shared album
3. Go to the photos app, delete some of those photos
4. Go again to the iCloud shared album and save again the some of the photos you deleted. You'll see this condition happen.

I found an updated code that seems to work better to handle the updating behavior here:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Photos/Reference/PHPhotoLibraryChangeObserver_Protocol/

But it still doesn't handle this situation nor when the indexes to be deleted are bigger (i.e. Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'attempt to delete item 9 from section 0 which only contains 9 items before the update'). I created this updated version of this code that deals with this better and hasn't crashed for me anymore so far.

```
func photoLibraryDidChange(changeInfo: PHChange!) {

    // Photos may call this method on a background queue;
    // switch to the main queue to update the UI.
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {


        // Check for changes to the list of assets (insertions, deletions, moves, or updates).
        if let collectionChanges = changeInfo.changeDetailsForFetchResult(self.assetsFetchResult) {

            // Get the new fetch result for future change tracking.
            self.assetsFetchResult = collectionChanges.fetchResultAfterChanges

            if collectionChanges.hasIncrementalChanges {

                // Get the changes as lists of index paths for updating the UI.
                var removedPaths: [NSIndexPath]?
                var insertedPaths: [NSIndexPath]?
                var changedPaths: [NSIndexPath]?
                if let removed = collectionChanges.removedIndexes {
                    removedPaths = self.indexPathsFromIndexSetWithSection(removed,section: 0)
                }
                if let inserted = collectionChanges.insertedIndexes {
                    insertedPaths = self.indexPathsFromIndexSetWithSection(inserted,section: 0)
                }
                if let changed = collectionChanges.changedIndexes {
                    changedPaths = self.indexPathsFromIndexSetWithSection(changed,section: 0)
                }
                var shouldReload = false
                if changedPaths != nil && removedPaths != nil{
                    for changedPath in changedPaths!{
                        if contains(removedPaths!,changedPath){
                            shouldReload = true
                            break
                        }
                    }

                }

                if removedPaths?.last?.item >= self.assetsFetchResult.count{
                    shouldReload = true
                }

                if shouldReload{
                    self.collectionView.reloadData()
                }else{
                    // Tell the collection view to animate insertions/deletions/moves
                    // and to refresh any cells that have changed content.
                    self.collectionView.performBatchUpdates(
                        {
                            if let theRemovedPaths = removedPaths {
                                self.collectionView.deleteItemsAtIndexPaths(theRemovedPaths)
                            }
                            if let theInsertedPaths = insertedPaths {
                                self.collectionView.insertItemsAtIndexPaths(theInsertedPaths)
                            }
                            if let theChangedPaths = changedPaths{
                                self.collectionView.reloadItemsAtIndexPaths(theChangedPaths)
                            }
                            if (collectionChanges.hasMoves) {
                                collectionChanges.enumerateMovesWithBlock() { fromIndex, toIndex in
                                    let fromIndexPath = NSIndexPath(forItem: fromIndex, inSection: 0)
                                    let toIndexPath = NSIndexPath(forItem: toIndex, inSection: 0)
                                    self.collectionView.moveItemAtIndexPath(fromIndexPath, toIndexPath: toIndexPath)
                                }
                            }
                        }, completion: nil)

                }

            } else {
                // Detailed change information is not available;
                // repopulate the UI from the current fetch result.
                self.collectionView.reloadData()
            }
        }
    }
}

func indexPathsFromIndexSetWithSection(indexSet:NSIndexSet?,section:Int) -> [NSIndexPath]?{
    if indexSet == nil{
        return nil
    }
    var indexPaths:[NSIndexPath] = []

    indexSet?.enumerateIndexesUsingBlock { (index, Bool) -> Void in
        indexPaths.append(NSIndexPath(forItem: index, inSection: section))
    }
    return indexPaths

}
```

Swift 3 / iOS 10 version:

```
func photoLibraryDidChange(_ changeInstance: PHChange) {
    guard let collectionView = self.collectionView else {
        return
    }

    // Photos may call this method on a background queue;
    // switch to the main queue to update the UI.
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        guard let fetchResults = self.fetchResults else {
            collectionView.reloadData()
            return
        }

        // Check for changes to the list of assets (insertions, deletions, moves, or updates).
        if let collectionChanges = changeInstance.changeDetails(for: fetchResults) {
            // Get the new fetch result for future change tracking.
            self.fetchResults = collectionChanges.fetchResultAfterChanges

            if collectionChanges.hasIncrementalChanges {
                // Get the changes as lists of index paths for updating the UI.
                var removedPaths: [IndexPath]?
                var insertedPaths: [IndexPath]?
                var changedPaths: [IndexPath]?
                if let removed = collectionChanges.removedIndexes {
                    removedPaths = self.indexPaths(from: removed, section: 0)
                }
                if let inserted = collectionChanges.insertedIndexes {
                    insertedPaths = self.indexPaths(from:inserted, section: 0)
                }
                if let changed = collectionChanges.changedIndexes {
                    changedPaths = self.indexPaths(from: changed, section: 0)
                }
                var shouldReload = false
                if let removedPaths = removedPaths, let changedPaths = changedPaths {
                    for changedPath in changedPaths {
                        if removedPaths.contains(changedPath) {
                            shouldReload = true
                            break
                        }
                    }
                }

                if let item = removedPaths?.last?.item {
                    if item >= fetchResults.count {
                        shouldReload = true
                    }
                }

                if shouldReload {
                    collectionView.reloadData()
                } else {
                    // Tell the collection view to animate insertions/deletions/moves
                    // and to refresh any cells that have changed content.
                    collectionView.performBatchUpdates({
                        if let theRemovedPaths = removedPaths {
                            collectionView.deleteItems(at: theRemovedPaths)
                        }
                        if let theInsertedPaths = insertedPaths {
                            collectionView.insertItems(at: theInsertedPaths)
                        }
                        if let theChangedPaths = changedPaths {
                            collectionView.reloadItems(at: theChangedPaths)
                        }

                        collectionChanges.enumerateMoves { fromIndex, toIndex in
                            collectionView.moveItem(at: IndexPath(item: fromIndex, section: 0),
                                                    to: IndexPath(item: toIndex, section: 0))
                        }
                    })
                }
            } else {
                // Detailed change information is not available;
                // repopulate the UI from the current fetch result.
                collectionView.reloadData()
            }
        }
    }
}

func indexPaths(from indexSet: IndexSet?, section: Int) -> [IndexPath]? {
    guard let set = indexSet else {
        return nil
    }

    return set.map { (index) -> IndexPath in
        return IndexPath(item: index, section: section)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this @batkru. This is an  improvement on Apple's bug infested sample version. In fact, now that i think of it, bug infested is probably  a too nice way to put it, it's more like bugs coming out of the woodwork of a rat infested sinking ship type of sample code they put up.

Comment: Still have crash when iCloud album is updated very frequently, had to switch to simple reloadData

Comment: @BlessingLopes It could be bug not in sample code but in UIKit also. I tested updated version of the Apple sample code with iOS 10 Simulator under Xcode 8 beta 2 and it is not crashing any more.

Comment: I've added a version of the working code for Swift 3 / iOS 10

Comment: Thanks for your code. But my select on cell has gone.

Comment: When you set `self.assetsFetchResult = collectionChanges.fetchResultAfterChanges` is it still right to check for `if item >= fetchResults.count`?

Answer (score 12):

I just moved the `reloadItemsAtIndexPaths` after the batch updates are completed to fix the crash of deleting and reloading at the same time.

From docs of `changedIndexes` of `PHFetchResultChangeDetails`:

> These indexes are relative to the original fetch result (the
>   fetchResultBeforeChanges property) after you’ve applied the changes
>   described by the removedIndexes and insertedIndexes properties; when
>   updating your app’s interface, **apply changes after removals and
>   insertions and before moves.**

```
PHFetchResultChangeDetails *collectionChanges = [changeInstance changeDetailsForFetchResult:self.assetsFetchResults];
[collectionView performBatchUpdates:^{ 
        NSIndexSet *removedIndexes = [collectionChanges removedIndexes];
        if ([removedIndexes count]) {
            [collectionView deleteItemsAtIndexPaths:[self indexPathsFromIndexes:removedIndexes withSection:0]];
        }
        NSIndexSet *insertedIndexes = [collectionChanges insertedIndexes];
        if ([insertedIndexes count]) {
            [collectionView insertItemsAtIndexPaths:[self indexPathsFromIndexes:insertedIndexes withSection:0]];
        }
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        if (finished) {
            // Puting this after removes and inserts indexes fixes a crash of deleting and reloading at the same time.
            // From docs: When updating your app’s interface, apply changes after removals and insertions and before moves.
            NSIndexSet *changedIndexes = [collectionChanges changedIndexes];
            if ([changedIndexes count]) {
                [collectionView reloadItemsAtIndexPaths:[self indexPathsFromIndexes:changedIndexes withSection:0]];
            }
       }
    }
```

Comment: Also make sure to add moves after the changes as it can cause some mix-ups when dealing with extras like loading indicators for the images.

Answer (score 7):

I implemented the code in [batkryu's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29370012/176376) in Objective-C.

```
- (void)photoLibraryDidChange:(PHChange *)changeInstance {

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

        PHFetchResultChangeDetails *collectionChanges = [changeInstance changeDetailsForFetchResult:self.assetsFetchResults];
        if (collectionChanges) {

            self.assetsFetchResults = [collectionChanges fetchResultAfterChanges];

            UICollectionView *collectionView = self.collectionView;
            NSArray *removedPaths;
            NSArray *insertedPaths;
            NSArray *changedPaths;

            if ([collectionChanges hasIncrementalChanges]) {
                NSIndexSet *removedIndexes = [collectionChanges removedIndexes];
                removedPaths = [self indexPathsFromIndexSet:removedIndexes withSection:0];

                NSIndexSet *insertedIndexes = [collectionChanges insertedIndexes];
                insertedPaths = [self indexPathsFromIndexSet:insertedIndexes withSection:0];

                NSIndexSet *changedIndexes = [collectionChanges changedIndexes];
                changedPaths = [self indexPathsFromIndexSet:changedIndexes withSection:0];

                BOOL shouldReload = NO;

                if (changedPaths != nil && removedPaths != nil) {
                    for (NSIndexPath *changedPath in changedPaths) {
                        if ([removedPaths containsObject:changedPath]) {
                            shouldReload = YES;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }

                if (removedPaths.lastObject && ((NSIndexPath *)removedPaths.lastObject).item >= self.assetsFetchResults.count) {
                    shouldReload = YES;
                }

                if (shouldReload) {
                    [collectionView reloadData];

                } else {
                    [collectionView performBatchUpdates:^{
                        if (removedPaths) {
                            [collectionView deleteItemsAtIndexPaths:removedPaths];
                        }

                        if (insertedPaths) {
                            [collectionView insertItemsAtIndexPaths:insertedPaths];
                        }

                        if (changedPaths) {
                            [collectionView reloadItemsAtIndexPaths:changedPaths];
                        }

                        if ([collectionChanges hasMoves]) {
                            [collectionChanges enumerateMovesWithBlock:^(NSUInteger fromIndex, NSUInteger toIndex) {
                                NSIndexPath *fromIndexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:fromIndex inSection:0];
                                NSIndexPath *toIndexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:toIndex inSection:0];
                                [collectionView moveItemAtIndexPath:fromIndexPath toIndexPath:toIndexPath];
                            }];
                        }

                    } completion:NULL];
                }

                [self resetCachedAssets];
            } else {
                [collectionView reloadData];
            }
        }
    });
}

- (NSArray *)indexPathsFromIndexSet:(NSIndexSet *)indexSet withSection:(int)section {
    if (indexSet == nil) {
        return nil;
    }
    NSMutableArray *indexPaths = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    [indexSet enumerateIndexesUsingBlock:^(NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
        [indexPaths addObject:[NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:idx inSection:section]];
    }];

    return indexPaths;
}
```

Comment: I made a tweak to your answer below that adds some synchronization for the  performBatchUpdates and assignment to assetsFetchResults.

Answer (score 5):

Finally read documentation (not from developer.apple.com, but in Xcode) and the right way to apply incremental changes is:

```swift
collectionView.performBatchUpdates({
    // removedIndexes
    // insertedIndexes
}, completion: {
    // changedIndexes (using collectionView.cellForItem(at: index))
    collectionView.performBatchUpdates({
        // enumerateMoves
    })
})
```

Before implementing this approach we had random crashes when items were moved.

Why this is correct?

"**removedIndexes**" and "**insertedIndexes**" go first because this indexes are relative to the original fetch result

"**removedIndexes**" - "*indexes are relative to the original fetch result (the fetchResultBeforeChanges property); when updating your app’s interface, apply removals before insertions, changes, and moves."
"insertedIndexes" - "indexes are relative to the original fetch result (the fetchResultBeforeChanges property) after you’ve applied the changes described by the removedIndexes property; when updating your app’s interface, apply insertions after removals and before changes and moves.*"

"**changedIndexes**" can't be processed with "delete"/"insert" because they describe items after insertions/deletions

"**changedIndexes**" - "*These indexes are relative to the original fetch result (the fetchResultBeforeChanges property) after you’ve applied the changes described by the removedIndexes and insertedIndexes properties; when updating your app’s interface, apply changes after removals and insertions and before moves.*

**Warning**
*Don't map changedIndexes directly to UICollectionView item indices in batch updates. Use these indices to reconfigure the corresponding cells after performBatchUpdates(_:completion:). UICollectionView and UITableView expect the changedIndexes to be in the before state, while PhotoKit provides them in the after state, resulting in a crash if your app performs insertions and deletions at the same time as the changes.*"

"**enumerateMoves**" is the last thing we should do.

"**enumerateMoves**" - "*The toIndex parameter in the handler block is relative to the state of the fetch result after you’ve applied the changes described by the removedIndexes, insertedIndexes and changedIndexes properties. Therefore, if you use this method to update a collection view or similar user interface displaying the contents of the fetch result, update your UI to reflect insertions, removals, and changes before you process moves.*"

Answer (score 0):

This is an improvement to @batkru's answer, which eliminates the need for the variable `shouldReload`:

```
func photoLibraryDidChange(changeInstance: PHChange) {
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
        let changeDetails = changeInstance.changeDetailsForFetchResult(self.assetsFetchResult)

        if let details = changeDetails {
            self.assetsFetchResult = details.fetchResultAfterChanges

            if details.hasIncrementalChanges {
                var removedIndexes: [NSIndexPath]?
                var insertedIndexes: [NSIndexPath]?
                var changedIndexes: [NSIndexPath]?

                if let removed = details.removedIndexes {
                    removedIndexes = createIndexPathsFromIndices(removed)
                }
                if let inserted = details.insertedIndexes {
                    insertedIndexes = createIndexPathsFromIndices(inserted)
                }
                if let changed = details.changedIndexes {
                    changedIndexes = createIndexPathsFromIndices(changed)
                }

                if removedIndexes != nil && changedIndexes != nil {
                    for removedIndex in removedIndexes! {
                        let indexOfAppearanceOfRemovedIndexInChangedIndexes = find(changedIndexes!, removedIndex)
                        if let index = indexOfAppearanceOfRemovedIndexInChangedIndexes {
                            changedIndexes!.removeAtIndex(index)
                        }
                    }
                }

                self.collectionView?.performBatchUpdates({
                    if let removed = removedIndexes {
                        self.collectionView?.deleteItemsAtIndexPaths(removed)
                    }
                    if let inserted = insertedIndexes {
                        self.collectionView?.insertItemsAtIndexPaths(inserted)
                    }
                    if let changed = changedIndexes {
                        self.collectionView?.reloadItemsAtIndexPaths(changed)
                    }
                    if details.hasMoves {
                        changeDetails!.enumerateMovesWithBlock({ fromIndex, toIndex in
                            self.collectionView?.moveItemAtIndexPath(NSIndexPath(forItem: fromIndex, inSection: 0), toIndexPath: NSIndexPath(forItem: toIndex, inSection: 0))
                        })
                    }
                }, completion: nil)
            } else {
                self.collectionView?.reloadData()
            }
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: a lot closer, but still getting errors if inserting... same kind of crash. I did another function like you have for deleting with the deletes for the inserts, and it worked well. the issue I have with both though is it creates duplicates until those collectionView cells are reloaded.

Comment: @Individual11 Do you have updated code for a version that handles the insertion crashes?

Answer (score 0):

So I did well with @FernandoEscher's translation of @batkryu's solution, except in the situation where an iCloud Photo Library with tons of changes was recently re-conneted. In this situation the collection becomes totally un-responsive and can crash. The core problem is that photoLibraryDidChange will get called again before the performBatchUpdates completion fires. The call to performBatchUpdates before a performBatchUpdates finishes seems to kill performance. I suspect that the crash happens because assetsFetchResults gets modified while the animation is running for its previous value.

Sooooo, here's what I did:

elsewhere in the init....

```
self.phPhotoLibChageMutex = dispatch_semaphore_create(1);
```

_

```
- (void)photoLibraryDidChange:(PHChange *)changeInstance {
    dispatch_semaphore_wait(self.phPhotoLibChageMutex, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER);

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

        PHFetchResultChangeDetails *collectionChanges = [changeInstance changeDetailsForFetchResult:self.assetsFetchResults];
        if (collectionChanges) {

            self.assetsFetchResults = [collectionChanges fetchResultAfterChanges];

            UICollectionView *collectionView = self.collectionView;
            NSArray *removedPaths;
            NSArray *insertedPaths;
            NSArray *changedPaths;

            if ([collectionChanges hasIncrementalChanges]) {
                NSIndexSet *removedIndexes = [collectionChanges removedIndexes];
                removedPaths = [self indexPathsFromIndexSet:removedIndexes withSection:0];

                NSIndexSet *insertedIndexes = [collectionChanges insertedIndexes];
                insertedPaths = [self indexPathsFromIndexSet:insertedIndexes withSection:0];

                NSIndexSet *changedIndexes = [collectionChanges changedIndexes];
                changedPaths = [self indexPathsFromIndexSet:changedIndexes withSection:0];

                BOOL shouldReload = NO;

                if (changedPaths != nil && removedPaths != nil) {
                    for (NSIndexPath *changedPath in changedPaths) {
                        if ([removedPaths containsObject:changedPath]) {
                            shouldReload = YES;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }

                if (removedPaths.lastObject && ((NSIndexPath *)removedPaths.lastObject).item >= self.assetsFetchResults.count) {
                    shouldReload = YES;
                }

                if (shouldReload) {
                    [collectionView reloadData];
                    [self fixupSelection];
                    dispatch_semaphore_signal(self.phPhotoLibChageMutex);
                } else {
                    [collectionView performBatchUpdates:^{
                        if (removedPaths) {
                            [collectionView deleteItemsAtIndexPaths:removedPaths];
                        }

                        if (insertedPaths) {
                            [collectionView insertItemsAtIndexPaths:insertedPaths];
                        }

                        if (changedPaths) {
                            [collectionView reloadItemsAtIndexPaths:changedPaths];
                        }

                        if ([collectionChanges hasMoves]) {
                            [collectionChanges enumerateMovesWithBlock:^(NSUInteger fromIndex, NSUInteger toIndex) {
                                NSIndexPath *fromIndexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:fromIndex inSection:0];
                                NSIndexPath *toIndexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:toIndex inSection:0];
                                [collectionView moveItemAtIndexPath:fromIndexPath toIndexPath:toIndexPath];
                            }];
                        }

                    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                        [self fixupSelection];
                        dispatch_semaphore_signal(self.phPhotoLibChageMutex);
                    }];
                }

                [self resetCachedAssets];
            } else {
                [collectionView reloadData];
                [self fixupSelection];
                dispatch_semaphore_signal(self.phPhotoLibChageMutex);
            }
        }else{
            dispatch_semaphore_signal(self.phPhotoLibChageMutex);
        }
    });
}

- (NSArray *)indexPathsFromIndexSet:(NSIndexSet *)indexSet withSection:(int)section {
    if (indexSet == nil) {
        return nil;
    }
    NSMutableArray *indexPaths = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    [indexSet enumerateIndexesUsingBlock:^(NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
        [indexPaths addObject:[NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:idx inSection:section]];
    }];

    return indexPaths;
}
```